# Data not showing in the database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form that submits data supplied to the database. I have the following code:

```
 <?php


$valid=true;
 function is_empty($field,$msg){
    if($field==""){
        echo $msg;  
    }
 }
if(isset($_POST['register'])){  
//PHP FIELD VALIDATIONS



if(is_empty($_POST['fname'],"First name is required <br/>")){
        $valid=false;
    }
else{
    $fname=$_POST['fname'];
}

if(is_empty($_POST['lname'],"Last name is required <br/>")){
        $valid=false;
    }
else{
    $lname=$_POST['lname'];
}
if(is_empty($_POST['email'],"Email is required <br/>")){
        $valid=false;
    }
else{
    $email=$_POST['email'];
}
if(is_empty($_POST['pword'],"Password is required <br/>")){
        $valid=false;
    }
else{
    $pword=$_POST['pword'];
}


if($valid==true)

{



require_once 'scripts/connect_to_mysql.php';
//====USING PREPARED STATEMENTS TO PREVENT SQL INJECTION
$sql = "INSERT INTO customer ".
       "(First_name,Last_name,Email, Password, date_added) ".
       "VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)";
$stmt=$conn->prepare($sql);//preparing the statement
if(!$stmt){
    echo "Unable to prepare: ".$conn->errno. " " .$conn->error;
}
//executing the statement
$date=date('d m Y h:i:s');
if(!$stmt->bind_param('sssss', $fname, $lname, $email, $pword, $date)){
    echo "Binding parameters failed: ".$stmt->errno. " " . $stmt->error;//bind parameters to sql statement. 
}
if(!$stmt->execute()){//executing the statement
    echo "Statement Execution failed: ". $stmt->error;
}

if($stmt->affected_rows==1){
    echo $stmt->affected_rows;
echo "<span style='color:green;'>Entered data successfully</span>";
}
else{
    echo "Your data was not saved! Please check your inputs";
}
    }
$stmt->close();//closing the perpared statement
$conn->close();//closing the connection   

}
?>
```

It echo`affected_rows` as 1, but when i check my table in the database, no new record has been added. Please what am i not doing right?

Comment: try echoing stmnt->lastInsertId() in success loop

Comment: Hi @CodingAnt The fields get posted into the database, even though they're empty. Please help.

Comment: you mean empty row is inserted with id, i mean you are able to get lastinserted id right?

Comment: @CodingAnt yes, if a user doesn't enter anything into the fields, it still gets submitted to the database.

Comment: do a cleint side and server side validation , and stop the insertion

Comment: I've done that, but it still submits to the database. Please refer to the code i posted. Thanks @CodingAnt